# How to render error codes in Rails JSON API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, json-api

I want to render error codes in my error responses as JSON API describes [here](http://jsonapi.org/format/#errors). I use `ActiveInteraction` gem and it uses `ActiveModel::Errors` under the hood for creating error objects. According to the [documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Errors/add) `ActiveModel::Errors` library just sets an attribute and a message if you want to add an error to your response object.

```
add(attribute, message = :invalid, options = {})
```

So how could I set a `code` property while adding an error?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extract from the rails api docs:

```
person.errors.add(:name, :not_implemented, message: "must be implemented")
```

Actually the ':not_implemented' is the code you need.